# Connect neo4j desktop with python using IP Address instead giving local host

Tags: python, localhost, config, ip-address, neo4j-desktop

In my python file I have mentioned below configuration:

```
graphDB=GraphDatabase.driver(uri="0.0.0.0:7473", auth=( "kaberi", "kaberi"))
instead 
graphDB=GraphDatabase.driver(uri="bolt://localhost:7687", auth=( "kaberi", "kaberi"))
```

Done changes in the neo4j.conf file:

```
# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=false
#dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473
#dbms.connector.https.advertised_address=:7473
```

to

```
# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
##dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
##dbms.connector.https.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7473
##dbms.connector.https.advertised_address=:0.0.0.0:7473
```

Then I restart my neo4j , getting this error:

> HTTPS set to enabled, but no SSL policy provided

even commented all of the lines under
Https SSL configuration in the conf. file.

Not sure how to do or where I am going wrong.